# How to convert the processer number to 32 bit hexadecimal value

Tags: linux, pid

I am trying to assign a particular process to a particular CPU core.
e.g $taskset -p  0x11 4106

I know from the example it is setting core 0 and 4 to "ON" and assigning it to PID 4106. Can someone help me understand the conversion from 0 and 4 to "0x11"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is to raise 2 to the power of the number of each processor, then add them all up.

For 0 and 4 we compute 2<sup>0</sup> and 2<sup>4</sup>, giving 1 and 16, respectively.

Their sum is 17, which in hexadecimal format is 0x11.

Comment: it worked. Thank you :)